# When I delete a rectangle how can I also delete its letter

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, svg

I was trying to delete some of the rectangles that were going out of bounds but when I delete them I can not delete their letters. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Also I want my rectangles to have opacity but when I insert this line of code `.attr("class", function(d){if((d.x + d.width)> width || (d.y + d.height)> height) return "delete"});` they lose their opacity. I am reading all (x,y,width,height,etc) from a csv file. My code is this:

```
 `<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

.rect { fill-opacity:.50; stroke: rgb(60,100,200); stroke-width:1px;}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->     
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 1024,
    height = 768;

    // width = 1074 - margin.left - margin.right,
    // height = 818 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);

  //     x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x + d.width  })]);
  // y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y + d.height  })]);

x.domain([0, width]);
y.domain([0, height]);
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
  .attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the data
  d3.csv("rectangles.csv", function(error, data) {

    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function(d){
      d.height = +d.height;
      d.width = +d.width;
      d.x = +d.x;
      d.y = +d.y;
    });



  svg.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return  y(d.y) - (height - y(d.height)) })
   .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.width) })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.height) })
   .attr("fill", function(d) {return d.color})

   .attr("class", function(d){if((d.x + d.width)> width || (d.y + d.height)> height) return "delete"});
   // .attr("class", function(d){if(d.x>0 && d.x < 1024 - d.width && d.y > 0 && d.y < 768 - d.height) return "delete"})

   svg.selectAll("rect.delete").remove();


  svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("fill","red")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) - (height - y(d.height))/20; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + x(d.width)/10; })
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {console.log(d); return d.txt});

 // add the x Axis
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

 // add the y Axis
 svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
});
 </script>
</body>`
```

Comment: add the rect and text to a separate `g` element per rect and remove the `g` if you want the `rect` to be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be simpler for you to instead of rendering your rectangles and then deleting them, to simply filter out the data before hand. The issue you're running into, is that although you use same data for text and rectangles, they don't really have links between them. As @rioV8 pointed out, a proper way would be to to use a `g` element to group related items together.

> Also I want my rectangles to have opacity but when I insert this line of code .attr("class", function(d){if((d.x + d.width)> width || (d.y + d.height)> height) return "delete"}); they lose their opacity

This happens, because `attr` overrides previous values, and since you return either "delete" or undefined, it doesn't have the "rect" class no more. When working with classes, instead of `attr` use `classed`, e.g.

```
.classed('delete', function(d){
    if (shouldBeDeleted) return true;
    return false; 
})
```

This way you toggle only `delete` class, and any other classes for the element are preserved.

Here is a demonstration how to filter data, and how to group related rectangles and labels into `g` element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
    svg { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: solid 1px; }
    g.item rect {
      fill-opacity: 0.2;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>


    var data = [{
        x: -50,
      y: 150,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      text: 'A',
      color: '#f00'
    }, {
      x: 100,
      y: 150,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      text: 'B',
      color: '#0f0'
    }, {
      x: 350,
      y: 150,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      text: 'C',
      color: '#00f'
    }];

    var width = 400,
        height = 400;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var items = svg.selectAll('g.item')
        .data(data.filter(function(i){
            return i.x > 0 && i.x + i.width < width && i.y > 0 && i.y + i.height < height;
      }));

    items = items.enter()
        .append('g')
        .classed('item', true)
        .merge(items)
        .attr('transform', function(d){
        return "translate("+d.x +"," +d.y+")";
        });

    items.append('rect')
        .attr('width', (d) => d.width)
        .attr('height', (d) => d.height)
        .style('fill', (d) => d.color);

    items.append('text')
        .text((d) => d.text);

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me a lot to understand how it works.